# For any $r$, $s$, $t>1$, then there's a group such that $x$ has order $r$, $y$ has order $s$ while $xy$ has order $t$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $r$, $s$, and $t$ be positive integers greater than $1$. How to prove that  there exists a finite group $G$ having elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ has order $r$, $y$ has order $s$, and $xy$ has order $t$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following theorem, proved in Milne's [lecture notes on group theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf), shows this result:

*THEOREM 1.64* For any integers $m,n, r > 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, and $ab$ has order $r$.

The proof uses the groups $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Other proofs have been given implicitly here on MSE, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751895/can-we-find-some-constraint-about-order-of-xy-in-a-group-g), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418287/possible-order-of-ab-when-order-of-a-and-b-are-known).

Comment: Thank you very much. That proof seems quite simple, shame that I haven't come up with that.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think it is a shame. It needs a good idea.

Comment: I review that proof and have problems with the existence of $q$. How exactly can we guarantee that there is a prime $q$ such that $2mnr\ |\ q-1$?