# Tesselation of hyperbolic plane are hyperbolic

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, tessellations, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Let’s take a tesselation $T$ of the hyperbolic plane (not necessarily regular), my intuition tells me that clearly $T$ should be hyperbolic itself (in the sense of Gromov or using $\delta$-slim triangles), but I haven’t find a proof of that.
I think it can be done by showing that $T$ is quasi-isometric to the hyperbolic plane, but I am not sure how to show this, or if there is another proof of this. Also I haven’t find much references about how the curvature is “preserved” after a triangulation. Can you please help me find a reference about this?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Hyperbolicity is a property of a metric space, and a tesselation is not *a priori* a metric space. Are you making some unstated assumption about a metric structure associated to the tesselation?

Comment: A tesselation as a graph doesn’t hold a natural “discrete” metric? View as the space of vertices, so I can define hyperbolicity using $\delta$-slim triangles

Comment: And how would the numerical value of the distance between two vertices be determined?

Comment: Are you assuming that a graph is metrized so that every edge has unit length? Then there are non-hyperbolic tessellations.

Comment: @LeeMosher the distance between two vertices is the number of vertices of the shortest path between those two vertices.

Comment: @MoisheKohan why? There is no problem when that definition holds for trees or other graphs that are not tesselations, here is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are allowing irregular tesselations whose edges have no geometric relation to the geometry of $\mathbb H^2$, it seems unreasonable to expect that a tesselation of $\mathbb H^2$ would inherit a large scale metric property of $\mathbb H^2$ such as Gromov hyperbolicity.

Keeping that in mind, and remembering also that $\mathbb H^2$ is actually homeomorphic to $\mathbb E^2$, it is then easy to construct an explicit counterexample.

To start with, pick a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb E^2 \to \mathbb H^2$.

Next, consider the Euclidean tesselation with vertex set $\mathcal V = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and edge set
$$\mathcal E = \bigl(\{[m-1,m] \mid m \in \mathbb Z\} \times \mathbb Z\bigr) \cup \bigl(\mathbb Z \times \{[n-1,n] \mid n \in \mathbb Z\bigr)
$$

Now transport that Euclidean tesselation from $\mathbb E^2$ to $\mathbb H^2$ using the homeomorphism $f$. You get a tesselation of $\mathbb H^2$ with vertices
$$f(\mathcal V) = \{f(v) \mid v \in \mathcal V\}, \quad f(\mathcal E) = \{f(e) \mid e \in \mathcal E\}
$$
From this construction, the tesselation of $\mathbb H^2$ with vertex set $f(\mathcal V)$ and edge set $f(\mathcal E)$ is isometric to the tesselation of $\mathbb E^2$ with vertex set $\mathcal V$ and edge set $\mathcal E$. The latter tesselation is **not** Gromov hyperbolic, and so neither is the former.

---

Here's an even more explicit construction, which produces an example whose edges are actually $\mathbb H^2$ geodesics. Start with the upper half plane model of $\mathbb H^2$ and the homeomorphism $f : \mathbb E^2 \to \mathbb H^2$ given by
$$f(x,y) = (x,e^y)
$$
Now transport the $\mathbb E^2$ tesselation to $\mathbb H^2$ as described above. This homeomorphism already takes vertical edges $m \times [n-1,n] \subset \mathbb E^2$ to geodesic segments in $\mathbb H^2$, because the vertical segment $m \times [e^{n-1},e^n]$ is already geodesic. However, the homeomorphism does not yet take a horizontal edge $[m-1,m] \times n \subset \mathbb E^2$, to a geodesic segment in $\mathbb H^2$, because $[m-1,m] \times e^n$ is a horocyclic segment in $\mathbb H^2$. To repair that, you simply replace that $\mathbb H^2$ horocyclic segment by the geodesic segment with the same endpoints $(m-1,e^n)$ and $(m,e^n)$, which is the segment of the unique Euclidean semicircle that passes through those two points and hits the horizontal axis $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ at right angles.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but still, I don't understand something, If I allow the tesselation to be regular, every isometry of the tesselation is itself an isometry of the hyperbolic plane, so the group of isometries is acting cocompactly and properly, hence Svarc-Milnor Lemma should say something about this, doesn't? Or am I confusing things? Something like, both, the hyperbolic plane and the tesselation are quasi-isometric, and hyperbolicity is invariant under quasi-isometries...

Comment: You do indeed need strong regularity hypotheses on the tesselation in order for that kind of argument to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "strong regularity"? My argument doesn't just need to have a group acting geometrically on the tesselation?

Comment: Your post did not refer to any group, and in fact you specifically ruled that out by writing "not necessarily regular", leading to my answer. A different question, focussing on a tesselation which **is** invariant under a group action, might be interesting. But regarding that situation I will add that there are a lot of references, and even some questions on this site, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104954/are-hyperbolic-triangle-groups-hyperbolic).